# SQL return script is not returning data

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I have an Sql Server script that is not returning data. My .net variables come back as null. I have other scripts built the same way that are returning fine.

```
    public List<float> FlowerTotal { get; set; }
    public List<float> TrimTotal { get; set; }
    public List<float> WasteTotal { get; set; }
    public List<int> result = new List<int>();
    public List<List<float>> resultTotal = new List<List<float>>();

    public List<List<float>> TotalReturns(int FileID)
    {
        using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand returnTotal = new SqlCommand();
            returnTotal.Connection = myConn;
            myConn.Open();

            returnTotal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileID", FileID);

            returnTotal.CommandText = ("[spHarvestedCannabisTotalReturn]");
            returnTotal.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = returnTotal.ExecuteReader())
            {
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     if(FlowerTotal != null)
                         {
                              FlowerTotal.Add(reader.GetFloat(0));
                              TrimTotal.Add(reader.GetFloat(1));
                              WasteTotal.Add(reader.GetFloat(2));
                           }
                  }
                      resultTotal.Add(FlowerTotal);
                      resultTotal.Add(TrimTotal);
                      resultTotal.Add(WasteTotal);
                      reader.Close();          
            }
            returnTotal.Cancel();
            myConn.Close();
            return resultTotal;
        }
     }
```

```
    [spHarvestedCannabisTotalReturn]
        @fileID int
        AS
        BEGIN
        DECLARE
            @flower FLOAT,
            @trim FLOAT,
            @waste FLOAT

                SELECT [Flowers(F)], [Trim(T)], WasteMaterial FROM 
        dbo.HarvestedCannabis
                WHERE FileID = @fileID

                RETURN @flower
                RETURN @trim
                RETURN @waste

        END
```

My variables below are coming back as null, What am I doing wrong? any help in the right direction would be great

```
FlowerTotal.Add(reader.GetFloat(0));
TrimTotal.Add(reader.GetFloat(1));
WasteTotal.Add(reader.GetFloat(2));
```

Comment: Is `spHarvestedCannabisTotalReturn` returning data?

Comment: @DanB when I run the sp in SQL yes it does

Comment: Problem 1 is that you can't use RETURN multiple times in sequence to return multiple values. Problem 2 is that you **shouldn't** use return to provide data to the caller (by convention it is used to indicate success or failure). Problem 3 - you never set the local variables declared in your procedure - but that is mostly irrelevant because your procedure should "return" a resultset. It does this but you need to address the issues above. Add "set nocount on" as the first line in the procedure.

Comment: Why are you using `RETURN` 3 times? That isn't for `RETURN` is for. If you want to return Scalar values (instead of or in additional to a dataset) use `OUTPUT` parameters. You never assign a value to the variables (such as `@flower`, so I don't know why they are there anyway).

Comment: To continue - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).  Once you fix the procedure and properly parameterize your query in your app, you should be able to retrieve the resultset.

Comment: And one last comment - it makes more sense from a <reading / understanding> perspective if you set the commandtype and text first and then add your parameters to it. Make your code easier to understand to help you and anyone else that must use or modify it at a later date.

Comment: Hi Mike.  Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @DanB Yes I did, I marked yours as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are that line `if(FlowerTotal != null)` that prevent result to be added to list<>.  Make sure all your list<> are initializated.

I think you can remove simplify your sp to :

```
[spHarvestedCannabisTotalReturn]
@fileID int
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT [Flowers(F)], [Trim(T)], WasteMaterial
        FROM   dbo.HarvestedCannabis
        WHERE  FileID = @fileID
END
```

That variable is not used `public List<int> result = new List<int>();`

Why a `list<list<>>` here? `public List<List<float>> resultTotal = new List<List<float>>();`